# Entity Framework generates DateTime in T-SQL with too many digits

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, entity-framework-5

I'm using the Entity Framework 5 and I've got a column `[Updated]` in a table of type `DateTime`. When I set `Updated` in a new entity (ID = 0) to let's say `DateTime.UtcNow`, Entity Framework generates an insert statement with a parameter e.g.

```
'2000-01-01 12:59:59.9991111'
```

This causes an error.

The error thrown by Entity Framework is ridiculus: *"DbUpdateConcurrencyException: Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. Refresh ObjectStateManager entries.*" However, I've obtained the query from an SQL Server Profiler, taken out the insert statement from an sp_executesql and then SQL Server gave me the real error: *"Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 1: Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string."*

I found that if I change the value to

```
'2000-01-01 12:59:59.999'
```

then the insert statement generated by Entity Framework works correctly.

I've tried a modulo when setting the `Updated` to set the last four digits to zero, but then Entity Framework produces `'2000-01-01 12:59:59.9990000'` which still causes an error.

Do you know how to force the Entity Framework to not generate those invalid zeros?

Regards

---

### Update:

I found that although Entity Framework uses 7 decimal places, it casts the date string as `datetime2` and then that `datetime2` is casted to `datetime`. This is why the decimal places doesn't cause the error as I suspected while inserting raw parameter values into insert statement (I didn't make a cast to `datetime2`). The cause of error has been found in trigger which interfere with `scope_identity()` and `@@row_count`. These values are checked by Entity Framework and in case of failure it throws a `DbUpdateConcurrencyException`.

The question that appears at the moment is: How to disable concurrency checking when inserting a new row?

---

### Update:

Database developers solved the issue by generating values to `@@row_count` and `scope_identity()` in their trigger. The important thing to remember is also to set a generated column name (`ID` in my case). It can't be leave anonymous.

**The problem was solved by satisfying the Entity Framework requirements from a database level. Be aware of triggers and their side effects when working with Entity Framework.**

Comment: "This causes an error" - what error? It's *always* a good idea to give the precise error when you're asking a question.

Comment: I updated the question. Hope it'll help.